# Как получить отсортированные данные из БД?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Приветствую. В БД `mysql` есть таблица со следующими столбцами: `id`(primary), `value1`, `value2`, `value3`... Так вот, я хочу получить данные, отсортированные по сумме столбцов `value`, то есть как бы `ORDER BY totalValues DESC`. 
Я, конечно же, могу создать дополнительный столбец "totalValues", который нужно будет обновлять при каждом изменении любого из `value`, но столбцы, напрямую зависящие от других - насколько я понимаю, не есть хорошо. И да, я могу потом отсортировать данные внутри своего PHP-скрипта, но можно ли получать готовые, отсортированные таким образом данные? Есть ли элегантные решения данного вопроса?

Comment: Пробовали `select * from table order by (value1+value2+value3)`

Comment: @Saidolim нет, но ведь `ORDER BY` выполняется для поля, разве получится сделать это для суммы полей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Order by напишите выражение, которое вы хотите отсортировать.

Вот пример:

```
CREATE TABLE valueTable
    (`id` int, value1 int, value2 int, value3 int);

INSERT INTO valueTable
    (`id`, `value1`, `value2`, `value3`)
VALUES
    (1, 2,3,4),
    (2, 4,4,4),
    (3, -2,-3,-4);
```

и запрос

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  valueTable
order by (value1 + value2 + value3);
```

и результат

```
id  value1  value2  value3
3    -2      -3       -4
1     2       3        4
2     4       4        4
```

[исходники тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7348f9/1)

Comment: Благодарю, не подозревал, что `order by` работает с выражениями.